# Profile photo is not updated Django 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

My problem is the following, I am creating users with the default Django model, creating a user automatically creates a profile associated with this user, with the date of birth and profile photo fields. A profile photo is assigned by default, when I want to change it it is not updated, although the rest of the fields do, I have searched for solutions but none has helped me. Here the code:

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    birth_date = forms.DateField(label='Fecha de nacimiento')
    photo = forms.ImageField(label="Foto de perfil")

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['birth_date', 'photo']
```

**views,py**

```
def editProfile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UEditF(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)        
        if form.is_valid() and extended_profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            extended_profile_form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UEditF(instance=request.user)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
            'form': form,
            'extended_profile_form':extended_profile_form
    }

    return render(request, 'registration/edit_profile.html', context)
```

**edit_profile.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <h1
            style="padding-top: 0.5em; font-size: 4em; font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;">
            Editar el perfil del usuario {{ user.username }}</h1>
        <div class="container" >
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-6" style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 2em; border-radius: 5%;">
                    <form method="POST" action="" novalidate>
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form|crispy}}
                        {{ extended_profile_form|crispy}}
                        
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary text-center" type="submit">Actualizar Perfil</button>
                            <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Read Praxis Project</p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

At the code level it does not show an error, but by console this comes out:

```
Not Found: /polls/edit/media/IMG_20200123_192312.jpg
[06/Jul/2020 02:41:17] "GET /polls/edit/media/IMG_20200123_192312.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2846
```

I really don't understand the problem, I'm new to using Django, if someone can help me it would be great and I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" novalidate>
```

Comment: Oh how simple! Thank you very much, that worked, how kind of you!